# Como inserir um audio/mp3 usando Cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp-2, html5-audio

Estou tentando na view isso:

```
 <?php echo $this->Html->media('musica.mp3'); ?>
```

mas nada aparece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo a **[documentação](http://api.cakephp.org/2.1/class-HtmlHelper.html#_media)** desse helper a saída seria assim:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->media('audio.mp3'); ?>

 // saida
 <audio src="/files/audio.mp3"></audio>

 <?php echo $this->Html->media('video.mp4', array(
     'fullBase' => true,
     'text' => 'Fallback text'
 )); ?>

 // saida
 <video src="http://www.somehost.com/files/video.mp4">Fallback text</video>

<?php echo $this->Html->media(
     array(
         'video.mp4',
         array(
             'src' => 'video.ogg',
             'type' => "video/ogg; codecs='theora, vorbis'"
         )
     ),
     array('autoplay')
 ); ?>

 // saida
 <video autoplay="autoplay">
     <source src="/files/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
     <source src="/files/video.ogg" type="video/ogg; codecs='theora, vorbis'"/>
 </video>
```

Existe a possibilidade do seu navegador não estar renderizando, veja dentro do html para ver se ele está imprimindo alguma tag.

Comment: Está renderizando, só não aparece na view.

Comment: verifique se o path do áudio está certo, veja se seu navegador tem compatibilidade com a tag, passe o parâmetro text dentro da array, se você visualizar o texto é por que seu navegador não tem compatibilidade

Comment: Já fiz isso, ele toca se eu usar html puro. A questão é por que o "$this->Html->media" não funciona...

Comment: Quanto ao caminho o Cake pega automaticamente na pasta "files".